# spring boot: maven command to download all dependencies

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, maven-3

In a spring boot project I would like to download all dependencies before starting the application.

When I run "mvn compile" first, it is downloading a lot of dependecies. But when I run "mvn spring-boot:run" after that, it still downloads tons of dependecies.

So what is the right way to download all dependecies like spring-boot:run does - but without running the application?

Thank you!

Comment: You should run `mvn clean package` or if you have integration tests `mvn clean verify` and afterwards you can run `mvn spring-boot:run`...

Comment: `mvn package` is a good choice. Another option is `mvn install`

Comment: Thanks. Does "spring-boot:run" execute "package" or "verify" too?

Answer (score -1):

Try running maven with -o switch to run your maven command in offline mode. This will use already downloaded dependencies in the local repository.